# Android build failure

Tags: android, ubuntu, makefile, compilation

I followed instructions from [here](http://source.android.com/source/download.html). After `$ repo sync` I tried to build it with `$ make`, but got this error:

```
host SharedLib: libneo_cgi (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libneo_cgi.so) 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../libz.a when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.a when searching for -lz 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libneo_cgi.so] Error 1
```

Using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Any help appreciated.

**UPD:** I found a [discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg103299.html), that claims, that problem could be that I'm having 64bit libs on my 32bit system.

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libz.so 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 2010-07-07 17:08 /usr/lib/libz.so -> /lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3

$ file /lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3
/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.3: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

How do I figure out, if that libz.so.1.2.3.3 is the right lib, and in case I have to replace it with the right one, how do I do it?

Also, `$ arch` says, I have an i686 architecture. Machine, I'm using is Lenovo ThinkPad SL500 with Core 2 DUO CPU.

Comment: cross-site duplication is usually frowned upon here, especially of you don't make a note of it. http://superuser.com/questions/161688/ubuntu-libraries-problem/161765#161765

Comment: @msw I duplicated this one after two days of no answers here. Hoped, that SU could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything works now, the solution was to install lib64z1-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install lib64z1-dev
```

**Edit:** now there's another problem, with ClearSilver, described [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/64-bit-java-818899/) and **finally resolved [here](https://superuser.com/questions/161688/ubuntu-libraries-problem/162545#162545)**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install libz.

```
sudo apt-get install libz-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

libz library has different name in different distros

`lib32z1` on debian system