# Unit testing the android platform

Tags: android, unit-testing, platform

So, I was finally able to build and debug the android platform (the process can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196634/android-build-failure)). Now, the question is: where are the unit tests, how do I launch them and where do I see results?

And also, is there any guide to android platform architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to run every unit test on Android src.

I don't know about the C code, but you can see that inside some git repos holding Android apps like [Contacts](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary) they have a tests folder which is an android test project. You can check how to run them [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html).

Comment: I'm trying to run unit tests for those apps using (for example) `adb shell am instrument -w com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`, but it tells me, that `INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.android.email.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`
What is the problem here?